# Retrieving Memory Offset Address Using Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to retrieve the offset address of a memory variable

this is wat i did

```
Mov CX, OFFSET data
```

but the offset data gave its 0000, may i ask why?

Comment: Are you sure the variable *isn't* at an offset of 0?

Comment: actually, im also not very sure..  im very new to assembly, n trying to figure out alot of things

        data db  1,2,3,6,3,199
 ele  db ?
 threshold  db 200

these are my memory variables

Comment: If you haven't defined any other variables before it, chances are pretty good that it's at an offset of 0.

Comment: oic,  okay thanks alot jerry!

Comment: Perhaps showing us more code would help us to shed more light on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is correct.. 0000 refers to the offset from the beginning of the data segment. So the offset is ds:0000 (this is the logical address). To get the physical address you have to multiply by 16 the segment (ds) then add the offset (0000 in this case) if I remember correctly. Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_address) for more info about the logical addresses and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_address) for the physical addresses.